# PHP & PDO: Can connect to DB; can't seem to query

Tags: php, pdo

It appears I can connect to my database using PDO, but can't execute any queries with it. Example:

```
 private function connect() {
      try {
           $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->sHost;dbname=$this->sName", $this->sUser, $this->sPass);
      }
           catch (PDOException $e) {
           die ($e);
      }
      print_r($link);
      $result = $link->query("select * from mt3_users");
      var_dump($result);
      $row = $result->fetch($result);
      die("Your id is: ".$row["id"]);
      //$link = mysql_connect($this->sHost, $this->sUser, $this->sPass);
      if (!$link) {
          echo "Failed to connect to $this->sHost!";
          return false;
      }
      return $link;
 }
```

This returns the following:

> PDO Object ( ) bool(false) 
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in Database.php on line 32

So basically, $link is coming back as a PDO object (I changed my username and password to see if an exception was caught; it was) and PDOConnection::Query is returning null for some reason. This is my first time dealing with PDOs -- am I doing something funny?

Comment: Code style suggestion: Don't put variables in double-quotes strings but use single-quotes strings and string concatenation to embed variables. Makes the code more readable and faster.
Additionally, if you want an exceaption to be fatal you don't have to catch them and die() manually.

Comment: How can you find literal strings + concatenation more readable? Variable interpolation in strings is the best part of having variables with sigils, the countless open/closed quotes and dots make an awful mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => 1046 [2] => No database selected ) Array ( )

Nevermind, I guess. It turns out that while migrating from using regular MySQL functions, I wasn't setting $this->sName ($this->sName was null. I'm half surprised it didn't throw an exception. Only half, though)

Fixed.

But thank you guys for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the query fails, are you sure of the name of the table `mt3_users` and that you have selected the right database? That error message shows that `$result` is not an object and that's due to an error in the query.

Also:

```
$row = $result->fetch($result);
```

should be

```
$row = $result->fetch();
```

unless you want to specify options to `fetch()`, but you don't pass the object as argument.

Answer (score 0):

can you give this a try

```
 private function connect() {
 try {
   $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->sHost;dbname=$this->sName", $this->sUser, $this->sPass); 
 return $link ;
 }
 catch (PDOException $e) {
 die ($e);
 }
}
$pdolink = $this->connect(); 
$rows = $pdolink->query("select * from mt3_users");
foreach($rows as $row ){
   echo("Your id is: ".$row["id"]);
 }
```

and if you need to stick with `fetchAll` function

```
  private function connect() {
     try {
       $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->sHost;dbname=$this->sName", $this->sUser, $this->sPass); 
     return $link ;
     }
     catch (PDOException $e) {
     die ($e);
     }
    }
    $pdolink = $this->connect(); 
    $q = $pdolink->prepare("select * from mt3_users");
    $q->exectue();
    $rows = $q->fetchAll();
    var_dump($rows);
    foreach($rows as $row ){
       echo("Your id is: ".$row["id"]);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the error in your query:

```
$result = $link->query(...);
if($result===FALSE){
   print_r( $link->errorInfo);
   exit();
}

// the correct way to fetch one row
$link->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // or whatever way you want to fetch data
```